# JLink does not produce redistributable image

Tags: java, jlink

For a while now I've been working with modular projects, but due to being constrained with filename and automatic modules, I had never got a chance to work with jlink tool to produce a redistributable application image. Today I've opted to start an independent project which does not import any external dependencies to prevent usage of the compatibility mode. The project consists of 3 modules and is in maven, so I will only be posting the jlink command snippet I'm using.

Project for reference: https://gitlab.com/Dragas/edu-day-demo, checkout the `modules-full` tag. Project is built with `package` goal, to prevent polluting your local .m2 repository. Project is already configured to pull dependencies so packaging and deployment would be easier.

The command I used to generate the jlinked image was as follows:

```
jlink \
   --module-path edu-day-runtime/target/dependency/:edu-day-runtime/target/ \
   --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
   --output edu-day-jlinked \
   --launcher edurun=edu.day.runtime
```

Invoking the command does indeed generate a jlinked image, which contains minimum required modules, java libraries and JVM binaries to run the project. Invoking the machine that built the image

```
edu-day-jlinked/bin/edurun 1 1
```

does run the project and outputs the following

```
Result of sum is 2
```

Meanwhile, attempting to run the same in containerized environment (here i'm using `bash:5`, a non-java image to simulate an environment where java is not installed) does not yield similar results. Instead, the shell does not seem to find a binary named `java`

```
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)/edu-day-jlinked:/app" bash:5
...(in container)
bash-5.0# /app/bin/edurun 1 1
/app/bin/edurun: line 4: /app/bin/java: not found
```

Upon inspection, the folder does indeed contain the binary called java

```
bash-5.0# ls -la
total 52
drwxr-xr-x    2 1000     1000          4096 Aug 23 07:53 .
drwxr-xr-x    7 1000     1000          4096 Aug 23 07:53 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000           116 Aug 23 07:53 edurun
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000         16688 Aug 23 07:53 java
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000         16712 Aug 23 07:53 keytool
```

But even invoking it directly (to show the help message) does not yield any results, besides the same message that the binary cannot be found

```
(in /app/bin/ folder)
bash-5.0# ./java 
bash: ./java: No such file or directory
```

What is more interesting is that even the keytool binary returns the same error

```
(in /app/bin/ folder)
bash-5.0# ./keytool
bash: ./keytool: No such file or directory
```

This raises a question: what went wrong? I haven't yet delved deeper into how jlink works, but my speculation is that it copies the binaries from my own java installation (openjdk 11.0.8+10 from arch repositories), and considers that to be redistributable. Or did I just miss some command line options?

Comment: „*`docker run -it -v "$(pwd)/edu-day-jlinked:/app" bash:5`*“ — Hi. Please can you upload your _`Dockerfile`_ to your gitlab repo somewhere? Either that, or paste it here in your question? Also, please can you elaborate on the meaning of „*Dragas is looking for a **canonical answer***“? TIA.

Comment: There is no docker file. I'm using `bash:5` as docker image, and only mounting the necessary directory to run binaries in it. Canonical answer being "An answer that would further elaborate how to use `jlink` tool, and how to prepare the target system to run binaries produced by that tool".

Comment: „*There is no docker file. I'm using `bash:5`*“ — Thank you Dragas. I assume you mean [*version 5 of the Bash shell*](https://itsfoss.com/bash-5-release/).  Would you accept a *canonical answer* that proposes using a _`Dockerfile`_ instead of _`bash:5`_? I do not know whether or not using _`bash:5`_ as a Docker image is common practice that is widely known by everybody who is familiar with JLink or Docker. Would editing your question to mention your use of _`bash:5`_ as a Docker image, be helpful information to someone investigating the problem you're reporting? TIA.

Comment: Added an explanation for `bash:5` usage.

Comment: „*Added an explanation for `bash:5` usage*“ — Thank you Dragas. Would you accept a *canonical answer* that proposes using a _`Dockerfile`_ instead of _`bash:5`_? TIA.

Comment: Well I am interested in what went wrong, besides deliberately not installing java, I suppose sure. But `docker` here is intended to simulate an environment which does not have java installed. It can be substituted with any other environment, be it new ubuntu installation or a cloud VPS.

Comment: Couple things I'm curious to learn, please, Dragas: (***1***) The OS you're working on? (***2***) The reason for your hesitation to mark neither one of the two (*so far*) answers as *accepted*? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that the test container (bash:5) doesn't use the same version of the run-time linker as the java environment.

The binary produced by the jlink will only run if there is a compatible linux run-time linker on the system.

The purpose of the run-time linker is to configure the binary for execution on the system - at the time you are building an executable the default run-time linker is hard-coded into the binary. You can inspect the run-time linker using a tool such as `readelf -l`, or `ldd` (ldd only works if it can find the run-time linker)

The default run-time linker for amd64 linux (e.g. ubuntu) is: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`

The default run-time linker for i386 linux is: `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`

On a `bash:5` container, the default run-time linker is: `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`

This is not compatible with the run-time linker for the jdk

The error: `/app/bin/java: not found` is caused because the run-time linker cannot be found for the binary. A dirty test of a jlinked VM in a `bash:5` container gives the same error.

When I get the run-time linker for the java I've used:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v (pwd)/edu-day-jlinked64:/app -w /here bash:5 bash

bash-5.0# /app/bin/java
bash: /app/bin/java: No such file or directory
bash-5.0# strings -a /app/bin/java | grep '^/lib'
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
bash-5.0# ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ls: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

Testing with the run-time linker that's on-board:

```
bash-5.0# /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 --list /app/bin/java
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe2852a3000)
libjli.so => /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so (0x7fe28528c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe2852a3000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x7fe285272000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe2852a3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7fe2852a3000)
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __read_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __memmove_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __printf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating /app/bin/../lib/libjli.so: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

so it definitely won't work here.

Let's use something 'standard'. As I had built the jlinked app in an ubuntu:focal container, with an installed version of java let's use one that doesn't have java built-in:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/edu-day-jlinked64:/app -w /here ubuntu:focal bash
root@865c9c12c029:/here# /app/bin/java
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)
```

so it will work in this case.

Reproducibility:

Built using:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/here -w /here ubuntu:focal bash

# apt-get update
# DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git openjdk-14-jdk maven
# git clone https://gitlab.com/Dragas/edu-day-demo .
# git checkout modules-full
# ./mvnw package
# rm -rf edu-day-runtime/target/classes
# jlink --module-path edu-day-runtime/target/dependency/:edu-day-runtime/target/ --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --output edu-day-jlinked    --launcher edurun=edu.day.runtime
# ./edu-day-jlinked/bin/edurun 1 1
Result of sum is 2
```

In an adjacent directory:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/edu-day-jlinked:/app -w /here bash:5 bash
bash-5.0# /app/bin/edurun 1 1
/app/bin/edurun: line 4: /app/bin/java: not found
```

In another directory:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/edu-day-jlinked:/app -w /here ubuntu:focal bash
root@200b4a98f9ee:/here# /app/bin/edurun 1 1
Result of sum is 2
```

Answer (score 3):

***TL;DR*** — The *`bash:5`* image uses a *C* library that is binary incompatible with the *C* library that was linked with your *`edu-day-jlinked/bin/java`* executable.

---

***The long version***

> „*…This raises a question: what went wrong?…*“

What's going wrong is your *`app/bin/java`* binary is failing to find the *C* library that it was originally linked to when you built your *`edu-day-jlinked`* executable on whatever machine you built it on locally.

The problem occurs because the *`java`* binary that *`jlink`* produced is linked to the [*GNU `glibc`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) library that your locally-installed JDK uses…

```
$ ldd edu-day-demo-modules-full/edu-day-jlinked/bin/java
        …
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa61a95b000)
        …
```

Whereas, the *`bash:5`* image runs in the [*Busybox*](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/building-busybox.html) Linux distribution. And Busybox does not use *`glibc`*…

```
bash-5.0# ldd app/bin/java
        …
        libjli.so => app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so (0x7f572a16d000)
        …
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f572a19f000)
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __snprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __read_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __memmove_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __printf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __fprintf_chk: symbol not found
Error relocating app/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so: __sprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

It uses a different *C* library: [*`musl`*](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html)…

```
bash-5.0# find / -name '*musl*'
/lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
```

It helps to understand the [*Linking*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) process. And it also helps to bear in mind that [*JLink builds a **custom** executable for a **specific** environment*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282#Motivation).

Your trial run on your local machine worked, because *`jlink`* built the executable ***specifically*** for your local environment.

***The proposed solution***

> „*…docker here is intended to simulate an environment which does not have java installed…*“

Here is a *`Dockerfile`* that successfully builds your application and the resulting image  „*does not have `java` installed*“…

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-13-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml .
COPY edu-day-sum edu-day-sum
COPY edu-day-runtime edu-day-runtime
COPY edu-day-api edu-day-api

RUN mvn package && \
   --module-path ${JAVA_HOME}/jmods:edu-day-runtime/target/dependency/:edu-day-runtime/target/edu-day-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
   --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
   --output edu-day-jlinked \
   --launcher edurun=edu.day.runtime

FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=build /app/edu-day-jlinked /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/bin/edurun"]
CMD ["1", "1"]
```

[*Docker best practice*](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) advises: „*Use multi-stage builds*“ (*like in the above `Dockerfile`*) when your aim is to build „*an environment which does not have java installed*“.

The *`FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-13-alpine`* stage of the multi-stage build, uses an alpine Linux image that has both Maven and a JDK specifically built to be compatible with the alpine distribution.

The *`FROM alpine:latest`* is a very small linux distro that ***does not have Java on it***. The *`maven:3.6.1-jdk-13-alpine`* layer is discarded as [*the Docker best practice*](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) docs says. The only *`java`* in the resulting image is the one in *`app/bin`*.

Comment: To miss something this simple! Afterwards I found an answer from Alan Bateman saying that you need to download target another JDK to produce binaries for target architecture. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47594270/6523288

Comment: @Dragas? You create a JLink runtime image for your local platform (*Ubuntu?*).  And you ***use*** a Docker img of the same platform to test it (*@Petesh's `ubuntu:focal`?*). Your title says „*redistributable*“. So I presume you intend to „*distribute*“ your JLink RT? But you never ***produce*** a [***distributable** Docker image*](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/java/chapters/ch02-basic-concepts.adoc#main-components)? The *No-Dockerfile* approach is a neat trick for development-time testing. But what form will your final, ***real*** distributable artifact be in? TIA.