# arm64 docker image built on arm64 machine (m1) does not create java runtime correctly with jlink

Tags: java, docker, jlink

I'm attempting to build a docker image locally on my m1 mac. The application inside of the docker image is a java application built with `jlink`.

When attempting to run the docker image with the java application embedded in it, i get an error saying `No java detected`.

When I enter into the container, and try to do `./jre/bin/java -version`, I get this error from Java

```
bitcoin-s@d672864e1b18:/opt/docker$ ./jre/bin/java
bash: ./jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

[From other places online, this appears that the targeted arch by java is different than the processor its running on](https://mkyong.com/java/bash-usr-bin-java-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error/)

However this is confusing to me, as I said in the title, this is built on an m1 mac with java that supports aarch64. I would imagine the jre produced by `jlink` would also support `aarch64` in the docker image?

Too be clear, i am running attempting to build AND run the docker image on the same host machine which is an m1 mac.

If its relevant, the version of java I am using on my m1 mac is

```
java -version                                                                                                               
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.32+13-CA (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I pull a remotely built linux version of the docker container, and attempt to run java inside the container, I get this error

```
./jre/bin/java -version
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [JLink does not produce redistributable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544874/jlink-does-not-produce-redistributable-image/63595415#63595415)

TLDR, the linker expected by jlink was an x86 linker `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, however since the CPU that i'm attemping to run the jlink'ed jre on is an arm64 CPU, it does not have a x86 linker.

The root cause of this is the fact that I built the jre on an x86 github actions machine, and tried to run this on an arm64 machine.

At minium, it would be *really* nice to have an improved error message for this by the jdk teams.

One absolutely baffling error message is

```
bash: ./jre/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

If you found this question, here is where you can track our teams workarounds for this:

https://github.com/bitcoin-s/bitcoin-s/issues/4369