# Create a personalised JRE with Java 15 on Windows for Linux and Mac

Tags: java, cross-platform, java-platform-module-system, jlink, jpackage

I have found a way to create a personalised JRE on Windows that I can use on Windows.

I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593409/create-java-runtime-image-on-one-platform-for-another-using-jlink) on this web site where the answer
was "you just have to use the Linux jmods directory to make a Linux personalised JRE."

So, using [AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk15-binaries/releases/download/jdk-15%2B36/OpenJDK15U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_15_36.msi), I tried to do that with the following commands:

```sh
jlink --module-path \jmodsWindows\ --add-modules java.desktop --output OUTWindows\java
jlink --module-path \jmodsLinux\ --add-modules java.desktop --output OUTLinux\java
jlink --module-path \jmodsMac\ --add-modules java.desktop --output OUTMac\java
```

But the personalised JREs that all three above commands created are the Windows one.

Is there something wrong with my commands? Is there a change in JDK 15 that affects how the `jlink` tool creates custom runtime images?

Comment: I use "OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)" version if that can change something

Comment: *all the create personalised jre are the Windows one.*, how do you infer that?

Comment: „*a similar question on this web site where the answer was 'you just have to use the Linux jmods directory to make a Linux personalised JRE'*“ — Are you referring to [*the one answered by Alan Bateman*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593409/create-java-runtime-image-on-one-platform-for-another-using-jlink)?

Comment: @Naman they have exactly the same size and a java.exe file.

Comment: @deduper yes that's what I tried.

Comment: It looks like you're using *pseudopaths* for the different JDK distributions' JMOD locations: `jmodsWindows`, `jmodsLinux` and `jmodsMac`. What you're showing us *could* be hiding the cause of your problem. You should replace those *pseudopaths* with real ones that more accurately represent the actual locations on your file system. If you're concerned about privacy, you could anonymize them by replacing your name, say, with your cat's name.

Comment: @deduper I tried with
``` jlink --module-path C:\Users\hydrolien\Formiko\jmodsLinux```

Comment: @deduper - Cats need their privacy too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@deduper I tried with :

```
jlink --module-path C:\Users\hydrolien\Formiko\jmodsLinux --add-modules java.desktop --output OUTLinux\java
```

And that's working !

That was just a problem of absolute or relative path.

thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Shall I write my solution as an answer? Would you accept it?

Comment: @deduper if you would like to do it, do it.