# Is the JRE that is installed on an a particular OS customized to only run on the OS it is installed on?

Tags: java

I am thinking of using jlink in java9 to create a smaller jre, but if I want to use jlink on my mac, and then copy the jre to a windows vm and use it, will this work? Or is the jre that is installed on my Mac OS specific for only macs, while the JRE on windows is only for windows?

Comment: It won't run. It contains executables compiled for a specific platform.

Comment: Having said that see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210288/how-to-create-cross-platform-executables-for-jdk9-application-using-jlink-comman).