# jlink packages current platform's binaries

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, graalvm, jlink

I am trying to build cross-platform archives of an application built using Java 11 and packaged with `jlink`.

For the cross-platform packaging I am basing my build on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593409/create-java-runtime-image-on-one-platform-for-another-using-jlink/47594270#47594270). I have managed to make my Gradle build download the target platform's JDK and invoke `jlink` with the appropriate `jmods` folder, however the target image always includes the binaries and JRE structure of the host platform (in my case Windows, meaning the generated `bin` folder always includes DLLs and Windows executables). If I supply the `--strip-native-commands` flag then no executables are included at all, although the DLLs still are.

Is there any way to make `jlink` package the correct JRE files?

**Host JDK:** `Windows Oracle JDK 11.0.10 x64`

**Target JDK:** `OpenJDK 11.0.2 x64`

**Sample Linux invocation:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10/bin/jlink.exe
  --module-path C:\projectdir\build\install\project-linux\lib;C:\projectdir\build\JREs\linux\jmods
  --add-modules com.acme.app
  --compress 2
  --launcher app=com.acme.app/com.acme.app.Main
  --no-header-files
  --no-man-pages
  --strip-debug
  --dedup-legal-notices=error-if-not-same-content
  --output C:\projectdir\build\packageFiles\linux
```

**GraalVM**

Using `GraalVM CE Java 11 21.0.0` yields:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid JMOD file: C:\jdks\graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0\jmods\java.base.jmod
```

Which makes it seem like GraalVM's `jlink` always attempts to use the host's JMOD files.

**OpenJDK**

Using `OpenJDK 11.0.2 x64` yields the same result of including the host's binary files in the created runtime image. The same behaviour is true for `Zulu OpenJDK 11.0.10+9 x64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: the problem was with my reference to the `jmods` directory of both the Linux and the MacOS JDK distributions.

For the Linux one I mistakenly setup the build to download version `11.0.1` instead of `11.0.2`, which ended up leading to the logic to flatten the hierarchy not flattening it. This means that the `build/JREs/linux/jmods` reference wasn't targeting any existing folder, meaning that `jlink` doesn't find the JDK modules there hence the host files being included.

The MacOS JDK has a completely different file structure so the flattening logic was just wrong. Ultimately this lead to the same missing `jmods` folder symptom.

With both issues fixed the `jlink` tool now correctly packages the target JDK's files when building cross-platform runtime images.